# Is there a way to see if the iPhone device has "Keyboard Clicks" on or off?

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, settings, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can my app get the current status of the Keyboard Click setting?

Or even better is there a way to turn off Keyboard Clicks while my app is running?

Answer (score 1):

This is a user system setting, so  I'm fairly certain you won't be able to turn this off for your app. From a user's perspective would it be a good experience to disable this even if you could? They expect clicks to happen when typing, so if they aren't hearing clicks even though they've explicitly enabled them they might assume it is in error.

Comment: There is no keyboard in my app, so that won't be a problem. 

I do however have a UIPickerView which is either clicking or not depending on the user system setting for keyboard clicks. This is a problem since my app is audio based and the extra sounds are distracting. If I knew keyclicks were turned on, I could popup a message suggesting they might want to turn them off. (Or I could make the undocumented call to turn off sounds in a UIPickerView.)

Neither of those sounds very promising, so I guess I need to roll my own "always quiet" UIPickerView.

Comment: Pretty annoying that it is still an undocumented feature. Maybe a one off splash on first launch of the app telling the user "For best results disable keyboard audio by going to settings->etc" wouldn't be too annoying?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the click sounds of a UIPickerView. Undocumented, but pretty safe:

```
if ([myPickerView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSoundsEnabled:)])
    [myPickerView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"soundsEnabled"];
```